Are there tools like Jqwik for easily testing Google API's time class? (DateTime, EventDateTime...etc)
I was working on implementing test code for Google Calendar-related logic and came across a library called Fixture Monkey. To briefly explain, Fixture Monkey is a library that facilitates the creation of test objects when using JUnit.
Fixture Monkey provides a plugin for Jqwik, so generating arbitrary values for time classes supported by Java, such as LocalDateTime, was straightforward.
Generating Random LocalDateTime Values Using Fixture-monkey & Jqwik
default LocalDateTimeArbitrary localDateTimes() {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    return DateTimes.dateTimes()
        .between(
            now.minusDays(365),
            now.plusDays(365)
        );
}


LocalDateTime generation TestCode
@Test
void localDateTimeRandomValueGenerationTest() {
    FixtureMonkey fixtureMonkey = new FixtureMonkeyBuilder()
        .plugin(new JqwikPlugin())
        .build();
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = fixtureMonkey.giveMeOne(LocalDateTime.class);
    System.out.println(localDateTime);
}


This class makes my life so much easier...
However, it seems that Jqwik does not support Google API's time classes such as EventDateTime.
Therefore, Fixture-Monkey also does not provide random generation of values for Google API's time classes.
So I'm curious if there's a library like Jqwik that supports Google's time classes.
And If there's a good library for testing Google Calendar API, please recommend one.
Have a nice day - kevin

Is there a straigthforward way to map from Java's built-in time/date types to the corresponding Google types? If so, you can just map over jqwik's time module arbitraries.

I don't think I found anything after looking into it... It seems like I'll have to create the library myself.
have a nice day - kevin

It feels like it's been about a month since I started creating the library myself..!
I've finally implemented a library that randomly generates Google time class (EventDateTime)
I decided to write a comment to explain the simple usage.

First, add the following dependency to your Gradle / Maven configuration.
It's advisable to check the following link to verify if it's the latest version.
// gradle

implementation 'io.github.yonggoose:event-date-time-maker:0.7.5'

//maven

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.yonggoose</groupId>
    <artifactId>event-date-time-maker</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.5</version>
</dependency>

Second you can create an EventDateTime as follows
EventDateTimeArbitrary eventDateTimeArbitrary = EventDateTimeArbitrary.builder()
    .setYear(2024)
    .setMonth(7)
    .setDay(7)
    .build();
EventDateTime eventDateTime = eventDateTimeArbitrary.getEventDateTime();

You can use the EventDateTimeArbitraryBuilder class to specify the year, month, and day, and you can also define a range using LocalDateTime.

This project is open-source and licensed under the EPL-2.0 license.
We plan to continue developing it for more features. Since it's still an early-stage library, there are many areas that need improvement.
GitHub repository URL: https://github.com/IDMaker-io/MaKer
If you'd like to contribute, please feel free to leave an issue!
